# Test whether every element of array is truthy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given an array `a`, what is the simplest way to produce a boolean value that is true iff every value in `a` is truthy?

#### EDIT:

Is it `a.every(i => i)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which checks every element in the array you call it on and returns true if every item matches the condition you pass it as an argument. For your case, you can pass it a brief lambda function:

```
myArray.every(i => i)
```

Or simply use the [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) constructor, which will straight away make whatever you pass it into a bool.

```
myArray.every(Boolean)
```

Therefore every item in the array has `Boolean(item)` called upon it, and if every one of them returns true then `.every()` will return true as well.

Comment: Yes you can.  It would make this answer much more valuable to future users (and perhaps the OP) if you explained *why* this works.  That is, a brief explanation of `every` and of the `Boolean` constructor would help a lot.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Agreed, I added some explanation and documentation links

Comment: @ScottSauyet I preferred the first version which was brief and to the point but okay.

Comment: @Museful: The point is that answers here are supposed to be for anyone who comes along later with a similar question.  They don't have to be verbose, but they should be thorough.